# How to clear all metrics it python prometheus client

Tags: python, prometheus

I am trying to clear all metric instances and i am using .clear() to clear all labels and values. But the problem is when I have a metric without labels if does not work.

`registry = CollectorRegistry() metric_instance1 = Gauge(name=metric.name, labelnames=metric.label_names, registry=registry) metric_instance1.clear()`

And this is working for me.

But the problem is when I have a metric without labels

`metric_instance2 = Gauge(name=metric.name, registry=registry) metric_instance2.clear()`

I get an error

`AttributeError: 'Gauge' object has no attribute '_lock'`

And this is because its does not have self._metics and self._lock.

So my question is - what is the way to clear metrics without labels?